# C# XNA Farseer - Creating Shapes From Textures

Tags: c#, xna, physics, farseer

I want to create collision vertices to attach to bodies in XNA with Farseer, according to loaded Texture2Ds.

A caveat, first of all. is that I'm not using Farseer for anything other than collision. Rendering and all other game code is done using my own engine. Farseer is just used as a background physics simulator (and will only tell me when a collision happens, and then I'll handle that myself).

I should point out here that I'm 100% new to Farseer. Never used it before.

So, if I create my List using BayazitDecomposer.ConvexPartition(verts), should I then store this data alongside the Texture2D objects; and then create List objects on the fly when I create my collidable actors? Or am I doing something wrong?

Furthermore, in the example at http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/documentation, it scales the vertices by Vertices.Scale()... If I keep all my Farseer bodies in pixel space, do I need to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, if I create my List using BayazitDecomposer.ConvexPartition(verts), should I then store this data alongside the Texture2D objects; and then create List objects on the fly when I create my collidable actors? Or am I doing something wrong?

You create an instance of the Body class from a list of verts using the BodyFactory. I would suggest doing this for each actor you have. However, you can save yourself some processor power by reusing bodies. So if an actor dies add the body to a queue and then snap it to a new actor that is created.

> Furthermore, in the example at http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/documentation, it scales the vertices by Vertices.Scale()... If I keep all my Farseer bodies in pixel space, do I need to do this?

Nope. However that means that a pixel is a meter as far as Farseer is concerned. I believe the formula for Torque if Radius * Force so anything reliant on a radius wouldn't behave as expected. I suggest making the metes equivalent to what actually is a meter in the game. Its just a bit of extra division.